# Comentário de "Vamos continuar esta discussão no bate-papo"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

Quando existem muitos comentários em um pergunta, é sugerido aos usuários continuarem o diálogo no bate-papo.

Ao iniciar um chat, é inserido um comentário automático na pergunta com o link da sala de chat.

O problema é que esse comentário tem um "ã" (`&#227;`) codificado em utf-8:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível corrigir essa tradução para os futuros comentários automáticos?

Comment: Confirmo que isso realmente ocorre, testei em 2 browsers diferentes.

Comment: @bfavaretto, este post não deveria ter a tag [tag:tradução]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente foi corrigido :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]